# How to execute ORACLE APEX PLSQL Dynamic Content

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, dynamic-content, import-csv

I am new to Oracle APEX, i am trying to import csv file then parse the file contents, actually we have various staging table, according to that i need to write some logic like below, can anyone please let me know how to execute plsql dynamic content in oracle apex.

```
DECLARE 
  p_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(50);
  p_file_name VARCHAR2(255);
  l_columns_item varchar2(4000);  
  l_ddl VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
 p_TABLE_NAME := :P120_TABLENAME;
 p_file_name := :P120_BRO_FILENAME;

 IF p_TABLE_NAME = 'DUMMY' THEN
  l_columns_item :=  'col001,col002,col003,col004,col005,col006,col007,col008,col009';
 END IF;

     l_ddl := 'select line_number,'
                || l_columns_item
                || ' '
                || 'from apex_application_temp_files f, '
                || '           table( apex_data_parser.parse(
                                                            p_content => f.blob_content,
                                                            p_add_headers_row => 'Y',
                                                            p_max_rows => 50,
                                                            p_store_profile_to_collection =>     'FILE_PARSER_COLLECTION',
                                                            p_file_name => f.filename )) p '
                || 'where f.name ='''
                || p_file_name
                || '''';
    execute immediate l_ddl;
    RETURN l_ddl;                   
END;
```

The variable l_ddl contain below query how do i execute using oracle apex plsql dynamic content

```
select line_number,col001,col002,col003,col004,col005,col006,col007,col008,col009,col010,col011,col012,col013 from apex_application_temp_files f,            table( apex_data_parser.parse(
                                                            p_content => f.blob_content,                                                                
                                                            p_max_rows => 50,                                                               
                                                            p_file_name => f.filename )) p where f.name ='a.csv'
```

Comment: You uploaded a csv into APEX Collection and you what to show the csv content in APEX?

Comment: What version of APEX?  Please [edit] your question to add that; recent versions have some enhanced features to do things like this.

Comment: Yes i need to parse(display) the csv file contents, as per i have selected drop down options, the drop down options contains various staging tables according to the staging table i need to store the csv file values to the staging table, the csv parse should change according to the selected options, so i need to execute the l_ddl query, i have used APEX Version 20.2, i have used htp.prn(l_ddl) then i can able to see the query but while i need execute that query i need use cursor or ref cursor right?, please correct me if i am wrong or could you please suggest some idea, thanks in advance.